# How to fetch cookie from browser and pass it with request in jmeter?

Tags: cookies, jmeter

When I see my cookie in browser,it keeps on changing every 1 hour.
I don't have any log in page in my UI.
Instead, one access token gets attached to the request cookie for authentication.
When ever I copy that access token and hard code it in my HTTP HEADER MANAGER,it works fine.
But once the access token gets expired,the test case fails.
So,how to get the access token/ cookie from request header of browser dynamically while sending request, to execute my test cases

Answer (score 1):

Add a [Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan

1. Open user.properties file and add `CookieManager.save.cookies=true` line.
2. Restart JMeter to apply the changes.
3. You can access the saved cookies with COOKIE prefix ,example:    `${COOKIE_CookieName}` Use this to add cookie value where required

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cookie Manager for this scenario.

Example:-

```
Name: VAR
Value: ${COOKIE_XSRF-TOKEN}
```

When

> CookieManager.save.cookies=true

in jmeter.properties file, the variable VAR has the value of the XSRF-TOKEN cookie

Check this [blog](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide) for more information.

Hope it helps.